# Using css select first 5 elements, but skip when there are specific classname

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, media-queries, less

Say I have a markup structure like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="product-card hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up">1 content no show red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up">2 content no show red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up">3 content no show red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card">4 content red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card">5 content red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card">6 content red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card">7 content red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card">8 content red bg</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
    <div class="product-card">content</div>
</div>
```

I wish to select first 5 elements, and for each of them (first 5 elements), apply style

```
.product-card { background: red }
```

However, if the first 5 elements, say some of them has classname `hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up`, then I wish to skip these elements, in my example, first three should not have red bg,  should be skiped,  then apply red bg for 4-8 div elements

I have tried something like below, but none works...

```
.hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up ~ .product-card:nth-child(-n+5) {
      background: red
}

.product-card:nth-child(-n+5):not(.hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up) {
      background: red
}


.product-card:not(.hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up):nth-child(-n+5) {
      background: red
}
```

It won't skip div contain classname='hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up', still make first 5 red bg anyway...
Need help... some code example would be really helpful
Cheers

Comment: You need something like `.hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up + .product-card,.hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up + * + .product-card, .hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up + * + *  + .product-card` and so on until you get the 5

Comment: Hi Afif, thank for the info, could you provide an example please:) cheers

Comment: I think best would for you to rethink this using JavaScript as it seems like a case with enough logic for you to stay away from a css only solution

Comment: i'd love js solution... but boss wont allow change anything in js :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7mpo1h50/

Comment: Hi Afif,  thx for the awesome example, it saves my day :) cheers

Comment: The fiddle won't of course work if there are no `hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up` classes. Just add five another rows, in the fiddle, of `.product-card:not(.hidden-tablet-portrait-and-up):nth-child(X),`—where X is 1-5—to make it work.

Comment: Hi guys, in fact, this is the full solution I expect to get : https://jsfiddle.net/bLhgze7j/6/ Cheers